# Lie bracket in Taylor expansion. What is the second order term?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds

Consider smooth vector fields $V$ and $W$ on a smooth manifold $M$. Let $\varphi_t$ be the flow of $\dot{x}=V(x)$ and for fixed $x\in M$ define
\begin{align*}
f(t) &= W(\varphi_t(x))-\nabla\varphi_t(x)W(x).
\end{align*}
**I'd like to know the second order Taylor expansion of $f$ about $t=0$.** Specifically,
\begin{align*}
f(t) &= f(0)+t\partial_tf(0)+\tfrac{1}{2}t^2\partial_t^2f(t_*)
\end{align*}
where $t_*$ is some number between $0$ and $t$ whose existence is guaranteed by Taylor's theorem with remainder in Lagrange form (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).

**What I've tried:** For the zeroth order term I get
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= W(x)-W(x) = 0.
\end{align*}
For the first order term I get
\begin{align*}
\partial_tf(t) &= \nabla W(\varphi_t(x))V(\varphi_t(x))-\nabla V(\varphi_t(x))W(x)
\end{align*}
and so $\partial_tf(0)=\nabla W(x)V(x)-\nabla V(x)W(x) = [V,W](x)$, the Lie bracket of $V$ and $W$. For the second order term I get
\begin{align*}
\partial_t^2f(t) &= \nabla^2 W(\varphi_t(x))\big(V(\varphi_t(x)), V(\varphi_t(x))\big)+\nabla W(\varphi_t(x))\nabla V(\varphi_t(x))V(\varphi_t(x))\\
&\qquad-\nabla^2V(\varphi_t(x))\big(V(\varphi_t(x)),W(x)\big).
\end{align*}
However, I'm not sure how to make sense of this expression. I think, for example, $\nabla^2W$ is a two-tensor, hence my notation $\nabla^2W(V,V)$. Putting everything together would give (dropping arguments to simplify notation)
\begin{align*}
f(t) = t[V,W]+\tfrac{1}{2}t^2\bigg(\nabla^2 W(V,V)+\nabla W\nabla V (V)-\nabla^2V(V,W)\bigg).
\end{align*}
Does this look correct? If so, what is the meaning of the second order term? If not, what is the correct expansion of $f(t)$ about $0$? If it helps, assume $M$ is compact.

Comment: Your tensor notation here doesn't seem to make much sense; something like index would be much more clear. Also, if you're familiar with the [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative), it can be used to make this computation more straightforward.

Comment: Also, you've defined $f$ so that $f(t)\in T_{\varphi_t(x)}M$, so the expression $f(t)=f(0)+\dots$ doesn't make sense: $f(0)$ and $f(t)$ belong to different vector spaces.

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks for the comments. So is there no way to define a Taylor expansion for the map $t\mapsto f(t)$ about $t=0$? As a first step I'm even content with letting $M$ be Euclidean space. This came up in a calculation I'm trying to do and it seemed quite nice that the first order term is the Lie bracket.

Comment: In order to differentiate $f$, you need to identify all of the tangent spaces $T_{\varphi_t(x)}M$ by choosing a local trivialization of $TM$ along the integral curve; a fixed set of local coordinates offer one possible choice of trivialization. One natural choice here is to pull everything back to $T_xM$ along $\varphi$:$$f(t)=d_x\varphi_tv(t)\\v(t)=d_{\varphi_t(x)}\varphi_{-t}(W(\varphi_t(x)))-W(x)$$where $v:\mathbb{R}\to T_xM$ can be taylor expanded normally.